# Square number math method not working (Default constructor cannot handle exception type)

Tags: java

The goal of my program is to ask the user to input a number, then use the custom method created to square that number and output the square. However, the problem arose when trying this. Please note this is my first program with using user inputted methods (Complete beginner at them)

error code

> Error: Default constructor cannot handle exception type
>   `java.io.IOException` thrown by implicit super constructor. Must
>   define an explicit constructor

Code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Squareit 
{
    BufferedReader myInput=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    {
        String input;
        int num;
        System.out.println("1-12");
        input = myInput.readLine();
        num = Integer.parseInt(input);
    }

    public void square(int num) 
    {
        int ans = (num * num);
        System.out.println(" is" + ans);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        Squareit t = new Squareit();
        t.square(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to format your code for others to correctly comprehend your question

Comment: Sorry, i always seem to have trouble formatting it correctly.

Comment: What are those two empty blocks at the bottom?

Comment: I believe I posted those accidentally.

Comment: is this the part of the constructor?
{ 
    String input;
    int num;
    System.out.println("1-12");
    input = myInput.readLine();
    num = Integer.parseInt (input);
  }

Comment: No its just sopposed to be a intro message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initializer  code is the problem.

```
BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
{ 
    String input;
    int num;
    System.out.println("1-12");
    input = myInput.readLine();
    num = Integer.parseInt (input);
}
```

You should create a constructor instead.

```
class SquareIt {
    BufferedReader myInput;
    String input;
    int num;
    public SquareIt() throws IOException, NumberFormatException {
        myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        System.out.println("1-12");
        input = myInput.readLine();
        num = Integer.parseInt (input);
    } ....
```

Comment: It says the return type for the method is missing

Comment: @user2133068 there should be no return type for a constructor. Perhaps you mismatched the constructor name and the class name?

Comment: Sorry, I spelled the class name and constructor names differently  - SquareIt and Squareit are not the same ;)

Comment: @user2133068 Fixed the capitalization problem.

Comment: The program works now except when the use now inputs a number given the range (1-12) the resultant output screen always reads "is.. 0"

Comment: @user2133068  Put a `System.out.println("Number is "+num)` after converting the input to an integer to see whether the input was correctly read.

Comment: did you mean "Number is " + ans ? because that just outputs the number inputted by the user?

Comment: i notice the last line "Squareit t = new Squareit ();
    t.square(0); if i put a 0 into the bracket it will always print out 0 as the number is..., is there a way to put num squared into it?

Comment: nevermined i got it to work by simply fixing the line public void square(int num) { into public void square(int x) {

Answer (score 3):

Move this entire block into a constructor not as an implicit super constructor.

```
private int num;
public SquareIt() throws IOException, NumberFormatException {
  BufferedReader myInput=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
  String input;
  System.out.println("1-12");
  input = myInput.readLine();
  num = Integer.parseInt (input);
}
```

Comment: I believe you still need to catch or throw the `IOException`

Comment: Yes sorry that is absolutely true

Comment: I believe the main would be a more appropriate place to have the user input (creating buffered reader) and it would give more flexibility

Comment: @JanDvorak And probably NumberFormatException too (even though it is a runtime exception)

Comment: @RudolphEst `NumberFormatException` is unchecked and doesn't need to be declared (though it's still nice to do it in the javadoc)

Comment: @Ron I think that is a question of style and where else user input needs to be read. But you have a valid point. The buffered reader may be needed again for other user input.

Comment: I was just going for the quick fix to his issue aside from the abstraction/style issues.

Comment: @JanDvorak I agree about NumberFormatException, though I've always thought it should be a checked exception, since it is as common as IOExceptions and people often forget to catch for it until time for testing comes.

Comment: @RudolphEst someone decided `scanner` should never throw a checked exception (so that it can be used before one learns about try/catch)

Answer (score 1):

You're constructing a BufferedReader and reading from it outside of the constructor, and this might throw an IOException. You must thus handle this exception by putting this instruction into the constructor, and declaring the exception in its throws clause:

```
BufferedReader myInput;

public SquareIt() throws IOExcption {
    myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    String input;
    int num;
    System.out.println("1-12");
    input = myInput.readLine();
    num = Integer.parseInt (input);
}
```

Note that it's a good habit to declare a variable only when you need it, and to initialize it immediately:

```
public SquareIt() throws IOExcption {
    myInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("1-12");
    String input = myInput.readLine();
    int num = Integer.parseInt (input);
}
```